# string index out of range despite proper indentation and range specified

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
t = int(raw_input())
while t:
    original_arrangement = raw_input()
    no_of_pairs = 0
    for i in range(0,len(original_arrangement)):
        if original_arrangement[i]=="<" and original_arrangement[i+1]==">": 
            no_of_pairs+=1
    print "%d" %(no_of_pairs)
    t-=1
```

Here I get the IndexError:

```
string index out of range on line 6
```

I do not understand why do I get this as `range(0,len(original_arrangement))` should work fine and my indices should range from `0` to `n-1`.

Comment: Also I found out if the input after 1 (i.e. for original_arrangement) is <> it accepts the string and if the input is >< it gives IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: If `original_arrangement` is `"abcde"` and `i` goes from 0 to 4, in last iteration you are checking `"abcde"[i+1]`, which is `"abcde"[5]`. Max valid index in string of length 5 is 4. As a result you get an index error.

Comment: Maybe you could use something like 'for index, char in enumerate(original_arrangement)'

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I tried writing the limits of range function as 0,n-1 where I initialized n to len(original_arrangement) and it worked! Thankyou! Could you explain why len(original_arrangement) as a parameter to range() didn't work>

Answer (score 1):

String indexes starts from `0` and ends in `len(string)-1`, so when you do `original_arrangement[i+1]` you are going out of index on last iteration.

```
s = "somerandomstringhere"

s[0]
Out[4]: 's'

len(s)
Out[5]: 20

s[len(s)]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-db5f35bae095> in <module>()
----> 1 s[len(s)]

IndexError: string index out of range 

s[19]
Out[7]: 'e'
```

Comment: but doesn't the range(par1,par2) function take the indices from par1 to (par2-1)?

Comment: @NishitMengar Yes but when you do `for i in range(0, len(string)):`, on your last iteration, you'll have `len(string)-1` as your `i` value. In your for loop you are trying to get `i+1`th value of string, which causes the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! understood!

Comment: @NishitMengar You are welcome. :) Also, if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The largest index is `len(original_arrangement)-1`, so `i+1` is for `i=len(original_arrangement)-1` too large. But simply use `count`:

```
t = int(raw_input())
while t:
    original_arrangement = raw_input()
    no_of_pairs = original_arrangement.count("<>")
    print no_of_pairs
    t-=1
```